# How to get rid of zeros of each array in a list of array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to do time series data analysis on all the fracking wells in pennsylvania, and naturally a lot of these are dry wells with 0 production. I want to create the histogram of each array inside the list without zero in it, therefore the total length of each array will shrink a little bit

```
P = [data3P, data4P, data5P, data6P, data7P, data8P, data9P, data10P]
for i in P 
N = []
for i in data3P:
if i >0:
    N.append(i)
N
```

I think I should do it in a for loop, but just not sure how to do that for all the arrays in the list. Shall I use a double for loop?

Comment: Which programming language?

Comment: It looks Pythonic, so maybe `P = [data3P, data4P, ...]` then `P = [i for i in P if i > 0]`

Comment: Have you got any non-working code to share? What are those data objects (numbers, arrays...)? If this is Python and they are arrays, maybe try `filter(None, P)`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It's python.

Comment: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() This is the error message from  TessellatingHeckler, must be something wrong with what I did

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with large amounts of data, numpy is your friend. You can create a masked array (where the zeros are masked), and apply the regular histogram function, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3623917/483620) for an example.

Comment: Thanks. I got "hist is not defined", which library shall I import to make it work.

Comment: @BowenLiu You need to use `pyplot.hist`

Comment: @BowenLiu, you need to import numpy as np. See: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/maskedarray.html. pyplot.hist is a reference to matplotlib, not the tool I was talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if this is what you need, but if you want to gather all the NumPy arrays `datanP` but without any zeros they might contain, you can do this:

```
[a[a!=0] for a in P]
```

It would help if you showed what one of those input arrays looks like, and what you'd like to get out of the processing you're trying to do.

Comment: That's an inefficient way to work with numpy arrays, plus it returns a list, not a numpy array.

Comment: It's not if he has a list of arrays. I can't tell what the input actually is.